# Check how many users answered keeps returning first value

Tags: django

I am trying to see how many users answered each option however it will give me the result of how many people answered the first option. Result object is where all answered are saved to.

Do I need to make a loop in the html? Would this not work as you cant call Result in to html and filter it ? How would I go around doing this. I see the counter is staying to the first value and keeps looping for each option, but I am confused on a fix for this.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        
    <head>
        <title>Admin Panel</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-gfdkjb5BdAXd+lj+gudLWI+BXq4IuLW5IT+brZEZsLFm++aCMlF1V92rMkPaX4PP" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    
        <style>
            body,
            html {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                height: 100%;
                background: #7abecc !important;
            }
            .user_card {
                width: 350px;
                margin-top: auto;
                margin-bottom: auto;
                background: #74cfbf;
                position: relative;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                flex-direction: column;
                padding: 10px;
                box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
                -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
                border-radius: 5px;
    
            }
    
            .form_container {
                margin-top: 20px;
            }
    
            #form-title{
                color: #fff;
                
            }

            #questionTitle {
                text-align: left;
            }
    
            .login_btn {
                width: 100%;
                background: #33ccff !important;
                color: white !important;
            }
            .login_btn:focus {
                box-shadow: none !important;
                outline: 0px !important;
            }
            .login_container {
                padding: 0 2rem;
            }
            .input-group-text {
                background: #f7ba5b !important;
                color: white !important;
                border: 0 !important;
                border-radius: 0.25rem 0 0 0.25rem !important;
            }
            .input_user,
            .input_pass:focus {
                box-shadow: none !important;
                outline: 0px !important;
            }
    
            #messages{
                background-color: grey;
                color: #fff;
                padding: 10px;
                margin-top: 10px;
            }


        </style>
    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container h-100">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
                <div class="user_card">
                    <div><a href="{% url 'dashboardAdmin' %}">(--</a> <br/></div>
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                     
                        <h3 id="form-title">Question Statistics</h3>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center form_container">
                        <form method="POST" action="">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <h6 id="questionTitle"> {{question.QuestionText}} </h6>

                                
                            </div>

                           <div> <h7> The Amount Of Users Who Answered Were: {{counter}} </h7> </div>
                            </br>
                            {% for option in options %}
                            <label for="{{ option.OptionID }}">{{ option.OptionText }} <br> This Option Was Chosen by:  {{counter2}} Users</label> <br>
                            {% endfor %}

    
                                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 login_container">
                                     <input class="btn login_btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
                                   </div>
                        </form>
    
                    </div>
                    {{form.errors}}
                    {% for message in messages %}
                        <p id='messages'>{{message}} </p>
                    {%  endfor  %}
            
                
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Model

```
class Result(models.Model):
    ResponseID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    userID = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    QuestionsID = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ChosenOptionID = models.ForeignKey(Option, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.ResponseID)
```

VIEWS for statstic

```
def question_statistics(request, id):
    question = Question.objects.get(QuestionsID = id)
    options = Option.objects.filter(QuestionsID = question)
    r = Result.objects.filter(QuestionsID = id)

    counter = 0
    for x in r:
        counter+=1
    a = Result.objects.filter(ChosenOptionID = options)

    counter2 = 0
    for y in options:
        a = Result.objects.filter(ChosenOptionID = y)
        for x in a:
            counter2+=1



    current_user = request.user
    if current_user.is_admin:
        pass

    
    else:
        messages.error("User is not admin")
        return redirect('dashboardPage')
    context = {'question' : question,
            'options' : options,
            'results' : r, 
            'counter' : counter,
            'counter2' : counter}
    return render(request, 'questionStatistic.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 'counter2': counter should be 'counter2': counter2. It's returning the answer to the first question because the variable you're calling is the counter for the first question.

Comment: It will still loop and give the same answer right?

Comment: Your model setup is a bit confusing. Can you provide some more context as to what the options are and what you're trying to do? Why can't you just do Result.objects.filter(ChosenOptionID=y).count()?